# Average over rows, excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data file where there is 26 row for one experiment, and then there is done 70 experiments, so there is in total 1820 rows. Then I want to take the average of row 2 to 5 in each experiment. I use the index function but I can not get I to work.

I have added a picture of the data, in column C it is seen that there is 26 for each experiment. So I want to take the average for row 2 to 5, then 28 to 31 and so on. The average is of the data in column J.

[image: sceenshot of the excel sheet]

Can somebody help me, I use version 16.12 of Excel on Mac.

Comment: Where do you want the averages? An extra column `K` with the averages aligned with the start of each experiment? Or a separate table with experiment number and average columns in successive rows?

Comment: Just in column K, so the average is beneath each other each other. So the average from 2 to 5 is in row 1 and 28 to 31 is in row 2.

Answer (score 2):

Paste the following formula into `K1:K70`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("J$"&ROW()*26-24&":J$"&ROW()*26-21))
```

This works as follows:-

- `ROW()` returns the current row number, which represents the experiment number.
- `ROW()*26-24` is the first cell in the range to be averaged.
- `ROW()*26-21` is the last cell in the range to be averaged.
- `INDIRECT()` converts the text representation to a cell range.
- `AVERAGE()` gives the required result.